# Visual Studio C++/CLR - (Mutex) cannot convert argument 3 from 'bool *' to 'bool %'

Tags: c++-cli

I tried using address operation in clr Mutex since I'm developing using winforms I can't really understand what does the % operator use in the declaration of the boolean variable. `Mutex(bool initiallyOwned, Syste::String ^name, bool %createdNew)` This is the prototype of the mutex function that I am using. and I just can't get it to work with my implementation, because of the third part of the parameter.

```
 bool createdNew = true;
    System::Threading::Mutex^ mutex = gcnew System::Threading::Mutex(true, "MyApplicationName", &createdNew);
    if (createdNew){
        MessageBox::Show("First Instance");
        Application::EnableVisualStyles();
        Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application::Run(gcnew ProjectMod::loginForm());
    }else{
        System::Diagnostics::Process^ current = System::Diagnostics::Process::GetCurrentProcess();
        for each (System::Diagnostics::Process ^ process in System::Diagnostics::Process::GetProcessesByName(current->ProcessName))
            if (process->Id != current->Id){
                if (IsIconic((HWND)process->MainWindowHandle.ToPointer()))
                    ShowWindow((HWND)process->MainWindowHandle.ToPointer(), SW_RESTORE);
                SetForegroundWindow((HWND)process->MainWindowHandle.ToPointer());
                break;
            }
    }
```

Can somebody please help of how should I go about with calling the Mutex function more specifically how can I deal with the third parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `&` "address of" operator to turn a `bool` into a `bool%`.

```
bool createdNew;
Mutex^ mutex = gcnew Mutex(true, "MyApplicationName", createdNew);
// Remove the ampersand ------------------ right here ^
```

---

Other notes:

- Things will work better if you don't limit yourself to checking `createdNew`. If it wasn't created new, you also need to try to lock it.
- Things will work better if you release the Mutex, rather than just closing the reference to it and letting it be deleted. You can do this by sticking a call to [`ReleaseMutex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex.releasemutex) after the call to `Application::Run`.
- You should pick a name that's more unique than "MyApplicaitonName". Generate a Guid, bang on the keyboard, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor expects a [tracking reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/extensions/tracking-reference-operator-cpp-component-extensions?view=vs-2019) for the third argument. The compiler will automatically create the tracking reference when you refer to the variable, so just drop the `&` address-of:

```
bool createdNew;
System::Threading::Mutex^ mutex = gcnew System::Threading::Mutex(true, "MyName", createdNew);
```

The above is the same as the step-by-step equivalent:

```
bool createdNew;              // variable to be set by the mutex constructor
bool% trackNew = createdNew;  // explicit tracking reference to 'createdNew'
System::Threading::Mutex^ mutex = gcnew System::Threading::Mutex(true, "MyName", trackNew);
```